# txt file to an specific format

Tags: excel, python-3.x, text

I have a .txt file with some data I would like to convert to xls. The txt file has this format:

```
    1325    2016-09-08 13:42:35
    1325    2016-09-08 21:52:24
    1325    2016-09-10 13:00:26
    1325    2016-09-10 20:47:39
```

and more data. What I would like to do, is to have a .xls file that contains, inthe first column the first number in the .txt file, in the second column the date of the process, the third column the time of the first process and in the forth time the last time the process was made. I do it manually because I don't know alot of programming, the only thing I could do was to convert it to .xls but basically the file was converted to .xls with no changes. The code I used I found it on internet. How can I do it?

The code I used is:
        from os import listdir
        from os.path import isfile, join
        import xlwt
        import xlrd

```
    mypath = input("Please enter the directory path for the input files: ")

    textfiles = [ join(mypath,f) for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) and '.txt' in  f]

    def is_number(s):
        try:
            float(s)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False        


    style = xlwt.XFStyle()
    style.num_format_str = '#,###0.00'  

    for textfile in textfiles:
        f = open(textfile, 'r+')
        row_list = []
        for row in f:
            row_list.append(row.split('|'))
        column_list = zip(*row_list)
        workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
        worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('Sheet1')
        i = 0
        for column in column_list:
            for item in range(len(column)):
                value = column[item].strip()
                if is_number(value):
                    worksheet.write(item, i, float(value), style=style)
                else:
                    worksheet.write(item, i, value)
            i+=1
        workbook.save(textfile.replace('.txt', '.xls'))
```

Comment: You say the file is converted to xls with no changes - isn't that what you are asking for?  If not, what changes do you want?  The code you show seems fine.

Comment: I want to convert it from txt to xls, instead of tabs, columns and just the first and the last hour of each day. I tried this but it just convert the file to .xls with no changes